# '$.signalR.transports' is null or not an object in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I am using SignalR on my project.It is working fine with mozilla and google chrome.When I load the page.During loading error message is shown in IE developer tool. The error is
'$.signalR.transports' is null or not an object  connect?transport=foreverFrame&connectionId=f233ca33-962e-4b47-9ec4-f4398fda38d0&connectionData=%5B%5D&frameId=1, line 5 character 9.

Also in error popup this message shown 
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.2)
Timestamp: Fri, 4 May 2012 06:06:17 UTC

Message: HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: http://127.0.0.1:81/AddItem/AddItem?CourseItemID=0&CourseID=9976&SystemObjectName=Discussion&IsCourseHomePage=1

Answer (score 1):

Think that you may need the json2.js file.  See here?

http://lostinthegc.blogspot.com/2011/09/signalr-doesn-work-in-ie-internet.html

Comment: There is conflict occur between jquery 1.5.1 and jquery 1.6.4.During loading SignalR this message shown Object doesn't support this property or method.When I remove script tag jquery 1.5.1.It works fine.And when I remove jquery 1.6.4 it again show same error message.Please help me for this